# MySQL query to get the longest texts that occurr most often

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table *t1* a text field *f1*. I have this query to find the top 100 most common values of *f1* along with their frequency:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, f1 FROM t1 GROUP BY f1 ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 100;
```

What I need now is a query to find out what are the longest values of *f1* that occur most often. That is, I want to first order the records of the table by frequencies (like the query above does) and then I want to order them by length and grab the top 100. I tried doing that with this query but it doesn't return what I want, it simply returns the records with the longest values of f1 (most of them with only 1 occurrences):

```
SELECT f1, LENGTH(f1) AS l, COUNT(*) AS c FROM t1 GROUP BY f1, LENGTH(f1) ORDER BY l DESC, c DESC LIMIT 100;
```

My table has more than 44M records in case that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you want to order by the frequency then the length, but you ask for the order by length then frequency. Reverse your `ORDER BY` clause.